# How to install Audacity 2.1.0

Tags: 14.10, audacity

The Ubuntu Software Centre has an older version and downloading Audacity from the website gave me a folder that doesn't seem to have a binary to start the program. How do I install version 2.1.0 in Ubuntu 14.10?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to compile Audacity from source. The "README.txt" as part of the 2.1.0 package states that:

> To compile on Linux, Mac OS X and other Unix systems, execute these 
>   commands:
>
> ```
>   ./configure
>   make
>   make install  # as root
> ```

Running these commands should install Audacity 2.1.0 onto your system providing you have the necessary dependencies to compile and install it. The [Audacity Sourceforge](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/download/source) page states that:

> **Dependencies**
>
> The wxWidgets library is required. Audacity 2.1.0 requires wxGTK
>   2.8.12. The libsndfile library is also required and is included in Audacity obtained from SVN. Installation of other libraries is
>   optional.
>
> CMake is required to build libsoxr which is now the Audacity default
>   resampling library.

Ubuntu should already have the required dependencies for Audacity, however you need development packages in order to compile. You could do this manually using `apt-get install` but because Audacity is already in the Ubuntu repositories we can run `apt-get build-dep audacity` to install all of the required development packages for us.

Now all you need to do is configure, make, and install Audacity as described in the readme file.

Comment: i tried installing assuming i had all the dependencies since the previous version worked. it gives me the error that i need wxwidgets. how do i install that, i cant find a tutorial that isnt half-ass like "heres a link to half a program. figure it out yourself". how do i install the required dependencies?

Comment: I have included additional information in my answer regarding the installation of dependencies.

Comment: this is outdated and inaccurate - check answer by Sepero below

Answer (score 15):

Run these commands in a terminal

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntuhandbook1/audacity
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install audacity
```

Source: http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2015/04/install-audacity-audio-editor-2-1-0-in-ubuntu-from-ppa/

Comment: Why use a ppa? Use the prebuilt binaries, or if you want the latest version, then the source code...

Answer (score 0):

These steps compile audacity on Ubuntu 20.04

... see https://wiki.audacityteam.org/wiki/Building_On_Linux

> preliminary install  conan   https://conan.io/downloads.html

> download its deb from above link then install it using

```
sudo apt install ./conan-ubuntu-64.deb 

sudo apt-get build-dep -y   audacity  # now install dependencies 

mkdir -p ~/src/github.com/audacity # create parent dir of git repo 

cd ~/src/github.com/audacity

git clone  git@github.com:audacity/audacity.git

cd ~/src/github.com/audacity/audacity

git submodule update --init

git clone --recurse-submodules   git@github.com:audacity/wxWidgets.git

cd ~/src/github.com/audacity/audacity/wxWidgets/

mkdir buildgtk

cd ~/src/github.com/audacity/audacity/wxWidgets/buildgtk

../configure --with-cxx=14 --with-gtk=2

sudo make -j$(nproc)  install

sudo ldconfig

cd ~/src/github.com/audacity/audacity

mkdir build

cd build

cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -Daudacity_use_ffmpeg=loaded ..

make -j$(nproc)
```

DONE so now lets launch it

```
~/src/github.com/audacity/audacity/build/bin/Release/audacity  #  execute to confirm it runs OK


cd ~/src/github.com/audacity/audacity/build

sudo make -j8 install   #  install binary
```

Bonus ... if you want to avoid seeing that popup message

> Save project before closing

when closing audacity lets edit the code and recompile :

```
cd ~/src/github.com/audacity/audacity

grep -r 'Save project before closing' * | grep cpp  #  find source code file which contains offending popup

vi  src/ProjectManager.cpp   #  edit file
```

in your editor search for string       Save project before closing

```
  depending on your source code version prior releases had this
```

old
if (!sbSkipPromptingForSave

new
sbSkipPromptingForSave = true;
if (!sbSkipPromptingForSave

```
   current audacity release 3.2.x  have this
```

old
bool ProjectManager::sbSkipPromptingForSave = false;

new
bool ProjectManager::sbSkipPromptingForSave = true;

OK now save file and recompile

```
cd ~/src/github.com/audacity/audacity/build  #  now lets recompile

make -j$(nproc)


~/src/github.com/audacity/audacity/build/bin/Release/audacity  #  execute and confirm popup does not happen


cd ~/src/github.com/audacity/audacity/build

sudo make -j8 install   #  install binary
```